# Determine slow/problematic peer in network

Tags: networking, debug

Is it possible to see which peer in the network along the way to the actual server is slowing internet speed?

On the server i'm testing internet speed and it's very very good, but from office it's very slow.

Pinging server gives fine results. Peers along the way to the server too via tracert and WinMTR software.

But when i'm trying to download something from the server, it's 0 or max 4kb/sec...

Is there some software, to see what peer is slowing file delivery?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know topology of network? What devices is between server and computers? Some switches, access point and cables. Try to connect first computer direct to server and test. No switches on the way. Unplug all from switch and connect one computer to switch and to server and test speed. Than connect next computer and so on... The speed could be lowered onserver, on switch, sometimes bad cable degrade speed or network performance. Also some computer could flood network with UDP packets.

Comment: Too bad that it's not my network. Guess without direct access to routers and switches it's not possible.